# ASP.NET: Deploying project with form autherication to webhost

Tags: asp.net, authentication, deployment

How do i upload the form autherication data in App_Data folder to my webhost? I have uploaded my project and everything works fine, beside the login. I get this error:

*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)*

When i try to use the login on the site. Is this error casted because i created the form autherication on my localhost, then the .MDF file is also created with the localhost connectionstring? If so how do i fix this? Generally how do i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the connection string used in web.config. If you put the automatically created database in `app_data` folder (aspnetdb.mdf), there should be SQL Express or SQL Server installed on the machine and it should support attaching database in `user instance` mode.

Comment: Is it a problem if its a SQL Server and not SQL Express that is installed?